# Magento and AJAX.Updater

Tags: ajax, magento

I have looked through all the responses here and on the Magento boards and still no luck.

I have drop down list of states, with an AJAX.Updater call to gather a list of retail stores from the state selected.  FireBug is showing me the RESPONSE is there and the HTML as well, but the code never fills in the DIV being specified.

Here is my call with str being the passed state abbreviation.

```
new Ajax.Updater($('txtHint'),'../php/getdealer.php?q='+str, { method:'get', });
```

Any thoughts as to why it won't display on screen?

Answer (score 3):

Should

```
new Ajax.Updater($('txtHint'),'../php/getdealer.php?q='+str, { method:'get', });
```

not be

```
new Ajax.Updater('txtHint','../php/getdealer.php?q='+str, { method:'get' });
```

Reference: http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater